# A question about the relativity of time

Tags: general-relativity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invariant spacetime - distance - Circular Motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8659/invariant-spacetime-distance-circular-motion)

I understand that the closer something travels to the speed of light, that time will stretch by a factor, and distance will compress by the same factor.

My question is, if something travels in a circle, close to the speed of light, what does the distance of the journey look like to them? They measure that the trip took them 10 minutes. And an outside observer says that the journey took 20 minutes, and the outside observer measured that they did, for example, 1000 laps of a circle circumference 1000 km.

So if the plane had a distance trip counter, what would it read? And if they were looking out of the window, would the circle still look like it had a circumference of 1000km?