# Where other frame observer will put new stick

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

my question is with relativity, if we draw    two circle of same radii and fill the perimeter with stick (very small so it cover whole perimeter) now if we rotate a stick with veey high speed comparable to light then according to length contraction we can add one more stick, this can be understood with curve space , but if a obsever is in frame of moving stick and other in our frame
So if again same happen then we add a new stick which according to us cover whole space , but my queation is how extra stick will be adjusted for new observer
My main question is that when extra stick will be added to circle after length contraction then how observer in moving frame will mannage extra stick ( bcz for him their is no length contraction).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146514/

Comment: ... or [Euclidean geometry in non-inertial frame](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201492/) or [Distance in relativistic circular motion in invariant spacetime](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8659/)

Comment: Are you asking about the [Ehrenfest Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox)?