# Confusion in Special Relativity: Rotating frame of reference

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, curvature, rotation

Suppose we are observing a rotating frame from an inertial frame, free from gravity, and try to measure the circumference of a circle drawn in the rotating frame. Since our measuring rod would be contracted if we measure the circumference but it would not if we are measuring the diameter, according to Einstein we would conclude that the circumference to diameter ratio will be greater than $\pi$, since we would measure circumference greater.

But shouldn't the circumference itself contract so that we would get the same ratio pi in both the rotating as well as stationary case, where the circle is drawn in the inertial frame itself?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8659/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121889/2451 and links therein. See also  [Ehrenfest paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox) on Wikipedia.

Comment: What about restrictions on the angular speed? For example, imagine a disc with its circumference equal to 350 000 km and its angular velocity of 2pi per second??